# How to pause on the last step of the animation before returning from start in an infinite animation

Tags: css, css-animations, font-awesome

Hello my goal is to pause the animetion for a moment 1s in the 90deg/lastframe then start it again.This is a simple animation to show user to rotate its screen to lanscape [Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/of4z8crg/)

```
<div>
  <div>
  Testing
  </div>
  <div>
   <div style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px">
            <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt mobile-rotate"></i>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>


  .mobile-rotate{
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  @-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); } }
  @-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); } }
  @keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); transform:rotate(90deg); } }
}
```

Comment: Add a step at x% that rotates the element to 90deg already, so that between that x% and 100% there effectively is no more rotation. Calculate what x needs to be based on your overall animation duration and the time for which you want it to stay still …

Comment: @04FS Thanks got it

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `50%` step in the animation and have the `transform` end there until the animation completes. In addition, I added a half a second to the animation duration, so that the `transform` could pause for a complete second.

```css
.mobile-rotate {
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.min.css">
<div>
  <div>
    Testing
  </div>
  <div>
    <div style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px">
      <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt mobile-rotate"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbadxL54/)

Comment: @J.Doe Glad it's working for you. If you're happy with the answer, I'd appreciate it if you could select it as the chosen answer.